# Contacting a dynamically created control

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic

I have created a `textBox` control on run-time for my winform application. The control appears just find once the form loads up, and works great too. However, I have just run into a problem as I realize I do not know how to write the code to write to a dynamically created control.

Let's assume I have created a button (named "Button1") on **design time**. In Button1's click event, (`Button1_Click`), I would like to write the word "Hello" to a textBox control that won't be created until the application is executed. Some code below:

#### C# Code:

```
// Create the textBox control
TextBox new_textBox = null;
int x = 10;
int y = 10;
int xWidth = 300;
int yHeight = 200;

new_textBox = new TextBox();
                new_textBox.Text = controlText;
                new_textBox.Name = "textBox" + controlName;
                new_textBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(xWidth - 10, yHeight - 10);
                new_textBox.Location = new Point(x, y);
                new_textBox.BringToFront();
                new_textBox.Multiline = true;
                new_textBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;

// Add the textBox control to the form
this.Controls.Add(new_textBox);
```

#### The Problem:

From `Button1_Click` event, I cannot get in contact with a control that has not even been created yet. Thus, Visual Studio will throw an obvious error that the control does not exist (because it doesn't).

> So, is there some way to dynamically call a control, and more
>   specifically, a textBox control?

Thank you for any help on the matter,

Evan

Comment: The compiler was not recognizing my control - Jim's answer worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the `new_textBox` at class scope. Then the compiler can access it. For example:

```
class MyForm
{
    TextBox new_textBox;

    void InitializeTextBox()
    {
        new_textBox = new TextBox();
        // initialization code here
        // Add it to the form
        this.Controls.Add(new_textBox);
    }

    void Button1_Click(...)
    {
        new_textBox.Text = "clicked";
    }
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! Thank you my friend.

Comment: Also, just to add a note, you can use find control in his parent, and modify their properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `new_textBox` a class member (member of the form). You can again assign it a value and add to the forms controls later dynamically.
It would be a good practice to check if is null in the buttonClick event, though.